# $\operatorname{ord}(ab)=\operatorname{ord}(a)\operatorname{ord}(b)$ in $U(\mathbb{Z}_n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Let $(U(\mathbb{Z}_n), \cdot)$ the group of the units of $\mathbb{Z}_n$, and $a,b\in U(\mathbb{Z}_n)$. If $\operatorname{ord}(a)=r$, $\operatorname{ord}(b)=s$, $\operatorname{ord}(ab)=m$, $\gcd(r,s)=1$ show that $m=rs$.

Proof:

- $ab^{rs}=1 \implies m\mid rs \implies rs \ge m$
- $\forall π\in \mathbb{N^*}:(ab)^π=1 \implies (ab)^{π\ r}=1 \implies b^{π\ r}=1 \implies s|πr \implies s|π$. Working similar, $r|π$. So, $rs|π, \forallπ\in \mathbb{N^*} \implies rs|m \implies m\ge rs$.

Is this proof true?

Comment: @Crostul You are right, forgot that gcd is 1. Thank you.

Comment: Your proof doesn't use the hypothesis $\gcd (r,s)=1$. Since this is a necessary hypothesis, something is missing.

Comment: The second line makes no sense.

Comment: No. It only proves that $ord(a,b) \mid ord(a) ord(b)$

Comment: I thought that it would be a good idea to say that from devision algorithm, we must have $υ=0$ because $m$ is the smallest positive integer such that $ab^m=1$...

Comment: @Chris why can't $\pi=0$ and $v=m$?

Comment: Also could you put parentheses around $ab$? What you have written now should be interpreted as $a(b^m)$.

Comment: @stewbasic Thank you for this comment. I corrected it. Any idea for tha second dot?

Comment: @Chris The implication $(ab)^v=1\Rightarrow v=0$ is incorrect. You have that $m$ is the smallest positive integer such that $(ab)^m=1$, but you don't have that $v<m$, only that $v<rs$.

Comment: I tried to correct my proof. Have a look please. Thank you all of you.